# Getting error 'interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV' using Tkinter on a Mac

Tags: python, tkinter

Once the login is successful and I can access the task-manager, 9/10 times I get an  'interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV' error when trying to click on either of the options (i.e. 'add task', 'view mine', 'view all', 'delete task', 'clear all', 'log out'). Would anyone know why?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


class LoginWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master  # Represents parent window
        self.master.title("Login Section")
        self.master.geometry('800x500')

        # Set the background color
        self.master.configure(bg="turquoise")

        # Create the username label and entry field
        self.username_label = tk.Label(self.master, text="Username:", bg="turquoise", font=('Arial', 19))
        self.username_label.pack(padx=10, pady=5)
        self.username_entry = tk.Entry(self.master)
        self.username_entry.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

        # Create the password label and entry field
        self.password_label = tk.Label(self.master, text="Password:", bg="turquoise", font=('Arial', 19))
        self.password_label.pack(padx=10, pady=5)
        self.password_entry = tk.Entry(self.master, show="*")
        self.password_entry.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

        # Create the login button
        self.login_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Login", command=self.login, font=('Arial', 19, 'bold'))
        self.login_button.pack(padx=10, pady=25)

        # Dictionary to store usernames and passwords
        self.users = {
            "admin": "password",
            "user1": "pass1",
            "user2": "pass2"
        }

    def login(self):
        username = self.username_entry.get()  # returns the input from user
        password = self.password_entry.get()

        # Check if username and password match
        if username in self.users and self.users[username] == password:
            self.master.destroy()  # Close the login window
            TaskManagerWindow(username)  # Open the task manager window
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Login", "Invalid username and/or password. Try again.")


class TaskManagerWindow:
    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username

        self.master = tk.Tk()  # Represents root window
        self.master.title("Task Manager")

        # Set the background color
        self.master.configure(bg="light green")

        # Create the task list
        self.task_list = tk.Listbox(self.master, width=50)

        self.task_list.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=6, rowspan=4)

        # Create the task entry field
        self.task_entry = tk.Entry(self.master)
        self.task_entry.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=30, pady=5)
        self.task_entry.insert(tk.END, "Task...")
        self.task_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", self.clear_entry)

        # Create the username entry field
        self.username_entry = tk.Entry(self.master)
        self.username_entry.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=0, pady=5)
        self.username_entry.insert(tk.END, "Attributed to...")
        self.username_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", self.clear_username_entry)

        # Create the add button
        self.add_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Add Task", command=self.add_task, fg="orchid4")
        self.add_button.grid(row=0, column=7, padx=5, sticky="se")

        # Create the view mine button
        self.view_mine_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="View Mine", command=self.view_mine, fg="DeepSkyBlue2")
        self.view_mine_button.grid(row=1, column=7, padx=5, sticky="e")

        # Create the view all button
        self.view_all_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="View All", command=self.view_all, fg="DeepSkyBlue2")
        self.view_all_button.grid(row=1, column=8, padx=5, sticky="w")

        # Create the delete button
        self.delete_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Delete Task", command=self.delete_task, fg="red4")
        self.delete_button.grid(row=2, column=7, padx=5, sticky="ne")

        # Create the clear button
        self.clear_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Clear All", command=self.clear_tasks, fg="red4")
        self.clear_button.grid(row=2, column=8, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nw")

        # Create the logout button
        self.logout_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Logout", command=self.logout)
        self.logout_button.grid(row=5, column=8, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")

        # List to store tasks
        self.tasks = []

    def add_task(self):
        task = self.task_entry.get()
        username = self.username_entry.get()
        if task and task != "type..." and username and username != "username...":
            self.tasks.append({"task": task, "user": username})
            self.task_list.insert(tk.END, task)
            self.task_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.task_entry.insert(tk.END, "Task...")
            self.username_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.username_entry.insert(tk.END, "Attributed to...")
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning("Task Manager", "Please enter a task and username.")

    def delete_task(self):
        selected_indices = self.task_list.curselection()
        if selected_indices:
            # Iterate over the selected indices in reverse order
            for index in reversed(selected_indices):
                self.task_list.delete(index)
                del self.tasks[index]
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning("Task Manager", "Please select a task to delete.")

    def clear_tasks(self):
        confirmed = messagebox.askyesno("Task Manager", "Are you sure you want to clear all tasks?")
        if confirmed:
            self.task_list.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.tasks = []

    def clear_entry(self, event):
        current_value = self.task_entry.get()
        if current_value == "Task...":
            self.task_entry.delete(0, tk.END)

    def clear_username_entry(self, event):
        current_value = self.username_entry.get()
        if current_value == "Attributed to...":
            self.username_entry.delete(0, tk.END)

    def view_mine(self):
        self.task_list.delete(0, tk.END)
        for task in self.tasks:
            if task['user'] == self.username:
                self.task_list.insert(tk.END, task['task'])

    def view_all(self):
        self.task_list.delete(0, tk.END)
        for task in self.tasks:
            self.task_list.insert(tk.END, task['task'])

    def logout(self):
        confirmed = messagebox.askyesno("Task Manager", "Are you sure you want to log out?")
        if confirmed:
            self.master.destroy()  # Close the task manager window
            root = tk.Tk()
            LoginWindow(root)
            root.mainloop()

    def run(self):
        self.master.mainloop()


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    LoginWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Try to outsource `TaskManagerWindow` in `def login` after `root.mainloop` and call `mainloop` from your new instance of `to.Tk`. Same applies for your `logout` function. It's a kinda weird logic anyway. How is it supposed to end?

Comment: To be honest, I would rewrite your code that you only have a single instance of `Tk` for the lifetime of this program. You seem to lack of a fundamental understanding for `tkinter` and `python`.